# Changing page background color with blur effect depending on slider image

Tags: javascript, css, image, blur

Is it possible to get a similar effect with JavaScript or CSS ? What would be the best method to accomplish this effect.

Basically what it does is it changes the background color of the page with some nice blur effect depending on the slider image.

See the example : http://www.gog.com home page slider. (I believe they are simply creating background image in photoshop for each slider image.

http://images-1.gog.com/23382bd5e4e5deb7036d68e04286120df2a1d424881fcafb21ecd2c9a5c24ab5_bg_1920.jpg

http://images-2.gog.com/a88f5d7a5161fb204d2f78adf14eea73e03dde54eb8ab516e50b077dcbb72cba_bg_1920.jpg

http://images-3.gog.com/ab956772ba01063aadfb8cda56d2e9ed3a6e0abd1534ce94b5f3a524e085656f_bg_1920.jpg

Comment: you could give the button from the slider "next" and "previous" click event handler. On click you can define some css properties to the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to accomplish this using jQuery.

It uses three fixed-position `div`s, and then it animates their opacity.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var id= 'd' + $(this).text().replace('Background ','');
  $('#d1, #d2, #d3').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: this.id===id ? 1 : 0
    });
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}

#d1, #d2, #d3 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#d1 {
  background-image: url("http://images-1.gog.com/23382bd5e4e5deb7036d68e04286120df2a1d424881fcafb21ecd2c9a5c24ab5_bg_1920.jpg");
}

#d2 {
  background-image: url("http://images-2.gog.com/a88f5d7a5161fb204d2f78adf14eea73e03dde54eb8ab516e50b077dcbb72cba_bg_1920.jpg");
}

#d3 {
  background-image: url("http://images-3.gog.com/ab956772ba01063aadfb8cda56d2e9ed3a6e0abd1534ce94b5f3a524e085656f_bg_1920.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>

<button>Background 1</button>
<button>Background 2</button>
<button>Background 3</button>
```

Comment: Do you think is it possible doing this without creating background images for each slide in real time ? Maybe picking up colors from image and creating some blur effects with CSS or JS.
http://images-1.gog.com/93d151973f69f9f23f4fff25c2acbe8e4e0bd942fe8c29fede78b24c1f2be723_800.jpg

Comment: Here's a jQuery plug-in that seems to do just that:  http://briangonzalez.github.io/jquery.adaptive-backgrounds.js/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var id= 'd' + $(this).text().replace('Background ','');
  $('#d1, #d2, #d3').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({
      opacity: this.id===id ? 1 : 0
    });
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  position: relative;
}

#d1, #d2, #d3 {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
}

#d1 {
  background-image: url("http://images-1.gog.com/23382bd5e4e5deb7036d68e04286120df2a1d424881fcafb21ecd2c9a5c24ab5_bg_1920.jpg");
}

#d2 {
  background-image: url("http://images-2.gog.com/a88f5d7a5161fb204d2f78adf14eea73e03dde54eb8ab516e50b077dcbb72cba_bg_1920.jpg");
}

#d3 {
  background-image: url("http://images-3.gog.com/ab956772ba01063aadfb8cda56d2e9ed3a6e0abd1534ce94b5f3a524e085656f_bg_1920.jpg");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="d1"></div>
<div id="d2"></div>
<div id="d3"></div>

<button>Background 1</button>
<button>Background 2</button>
<button>Background 3</button>
```